# How to specify a type hint for a Pandas series expression

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I define Boolean expressions with type hints to match rows in a pandas DataFrame. The PyCharm code inspection tool flags these expressions.

For example, consider the code snippet below given a DataFrame `holdings` with fields `IsCash` and `Weight`:

```
predicate_iscash: pandas.Series = holdings.IsCash == True
predicate_short: pandas.Series = predicate_is_cash & (holdings.Weight < 0)
```

The second line is flagged by the code inspector with the following warning:

```
Unexpected type(s): (Series) Possible type(s): (bool) (int)
```

Strangely, the following statement is not flagged:

```
predicate_short: pandas.Series = (holdings.IsCash == True) & (holdings.Weight < 0)
```

But, I don't want to inline `predicate_iscash` since it is used in several locations in the code.

What workaround can I used to ensure that the code passes inspection?

Answer (score 0):

The following works and passes code inspection:

```
predicate_iscash: pandas.Series = holdings.IsCash == True
predicate_short: pandas.Series = predicate_is_cash & holdings.Weight.le(0)
```